# FadeIn DIV after AJAX pull

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have this bit of nasty code :P that updates a div using AJAX, but i would love to see a fadein effect on it. The thing is, i have an image that loads and appears during the interval where the div is not showing any content yet. Analyse the bottom of it. What can i do to make it fadein?

```
function testing(str)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
$('#myDiv').html('<div style="text-align:center; padding-top:195px;"><img src="../images/loaderajax.gif" width="220" height="19" /></div>');
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
$('#myDiv').hide();
xmlhttp.send();
$('#myDiv').fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: You're using jquery, why not use it for everything?  The AJAX is much cleaner if you just use jquery.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use jQuery's AJAX functionality?

Comment: At the time i wasn't using any framework (jQuery), just learning JS, i will reformulate the code soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are okay with wrapping the returned content, I would do something like this in the ajax response:

```
$("<div/>").html(xmlhttp.responseText).appendTo("#myDiv").hide().fadeIn();
```

This will allow your image to show and only fade in the new content.

Comment: Actually, this line didn't worked, but thanks for the hint, this worked:

     `$("#myDiv").html(xmlhttp.responseText).hide().fadeIn();`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is all wacky and out of order with your ajax call. You're using JQuery, so take advantage of it! :)

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'getuser.php',
   data: str,
   beforeSend(jqXHR, settings) {
        $('#myDiv').html('<div style="text-align:center; padding-top:195px;"><img src="../images/loaderajax.gif" width="220" height="19" /></div>');
    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#myDiv').html(textStatus + ' -- ' + errorThrown);
    },
    success:function(data){
        $('#myDiv').hide().html(data).fadeIn();
    }
 });
```

Comment: It works, but doesn't allow the loading image to appear :s
Many thanks, as a last resource i will use this code and forget about the loading image.

Comment: The loading image appears in the `beforeSend` call. If it's too fast, well I suppose that's a good thing ;)

Comment: Are you sure the code will work? Because there is a GET method in the middle:


xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);

Comment: Yes, the default `type` for JQuery's `$.ajax()` is `GET`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: But how can i define the srt variable through a function call? 

ajax(str);?

Comment: Simply define it somewhere outside the function just like you did with the `testing(str)` function. here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/8Afr5/

Comment: oh it's kinda obvious :P , first time using jquery to make ajax calls. 

`function testing(str)
{
$.ajax({
   url: 'getuser.php',
   data: str,
   beforeSend(jqXHR, settings) {
        $('#myDiv').html('<div style="text-align:center; padding-top:195px;"><img src="../images/loaderajax.gif" width="220" height="19" /></div>');
    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#myDiv').html(textStatus + ' -- ' + errorThrown);
    },
    success:function(data){
        $('#myDiv').hide().html(data).fadeIn();
    }
 });
}`
So this should work but it doesn't :S

Comment: So what gets put into `$('#myDiv')` ?

Comment: The myDiv is the div that should receive the content from an outside php file, but the problem is that if i use this code, it simply makes all the JS to stop running :(

Comment: There has to be an error somewhere else in your script. Check your console.

Answer (score 0):

Put the fadein() call in the code that handles the response.

Any reason why you're using jQuery for the selectors and effects and not for the AJAX?

Comment: At the time i wasn't using any library, just learning javascript. I will reformulate the code soon.